# Finding a swap device location from the virtual address

Tags: c, linux-kernel, swap, page-tables

With the virtual address, I am trying to find out the exact location of the swap device where the data is stored (e.g., the sector) in my kernel module.
I read from here (https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand014.html) that swap entry information is stored in the page table, so I tried something like this:

```
// Get PTE for the virtual address
mm = current->mm;
pgd = pgd_offset(mm, (unsigned long)addr);  
p4d = p4d_offset(pgd, (unsigned long)addr);
pud = pud_offset(p4d, (unsigned long)addr);
pmd = pmd_offset(pud, (unsigned long)addr);  
pte = pte_offset_map(pmd, (unsigned long)addr);  

// Get swap device position for the PTE
swp_entry = pte_to_swp_entry(*pte);
printk(KERN_INFO "Swap entry: %lu", swp_entry.val);
swap_offset = swp_offset(swp_entry);
printk(KERN_INFO "Swap offset: %lu", swap_offset);
```

From my understanding, the swap_offset I am getting is an index to a swap_map array, which can be as large as 2^24 entries (covering 64GB of swap space).
However, the swap_offset value I am getting is too large, larger than 2^24.
With the swap_offset correctly known, my idea was to assume that it represents an offset from swap device starting point (maybe with some division to get the sector number).

Am I understanding something wrong? If I'm totally in the wrong direction, how can I know the swap space location from the virtual address?

Any help is highly appreciated! Thank you.